# React / Redux TypeError: Cannot read property 'Requests' of undefined in component

Tags: reactjs, redux, use-effect

I am encountering an issue with my react-redux component where when it is initially loaded for the first time, it throws an error that the 'Requests' props passed by Redux are Undefined.

I know that when using `useEffect` the component loads while the call to Redux is happening Asynchronously.

I also know that my Redux call is working because the response is logged to the console successfully, only AFTER the 'undefined' error is thrown.

I still want to call `useEffect` each time this page is loaded.

Any suggestions on how to get the initial page load to work?

**COMPONENT**

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

import {requestlistbyowner} from '../../actions/request';
import { Card, ListGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';



const MyRequestList = ({requestlistbyowner, requestList: {Requests, loading}}) => { // THIS IS THE LINE THROWING THE ERROR AT 'Requests' and 'loading' BEING UNDEFINED

    useEffect(() => {
        requestlistbyowner();
    }, [requestlistbyowner]);

    
    return (
        <>
        <h1>request list</h1>
        {loading ? (
            <h2>Loading...</h2>
        ): (
          <Card>
            <Card.Header>Your Current Requests</Card.Header>
            <Card.Body>
                <ListGroup variant="flush">
                    {Requests.length > 0 ?  (
                        Requests.map(request =>(
                            <ListGroup.Item action key={request.id}><Link to={`/myrequest/${request.id}`}>{request.firstname}</Link> <span >{request.surname}</span></ListGroup.Item>
                            )
                        )
                    
                    ): 
                    ( <ListGroup.Item action>You Have No Saved Requests</ListGroup.Item>)}
                </ListGroup>
            </Card.Body> 
        </Card>  
        )} 
        </>
    )
}

MyRequestList.propTypes = {
    requestlistbyowner: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    requestList: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    requestList: state.Requests
 });

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {requestlistbyowner}) (MyRequestList)
```

**ACTION**

```
  /* GET ALL REQUESTS BY OWNER*/
  export const requestlistbyowner = () => async dispatch => {
     dispatch({ type: CLEAR_REQUEST });
      try {
          const res =  await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listRequests))
          console.log('listrequests: ', res.data.listRequests.items);

          dispatch({
              type: LIST_REQUESTS,
              payload: res.data.listRequests.items
          })
      } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error Listing All Requests By Owner: ', error);

          dispatch(setAlert(error.message, 'danger'))
          dispatch({
              type: REQUEST_FAIL
          });
      }
  }
```

**REDUCER**

```
import {
    CREATE_REQUEST,
    UPDATE_REQUEST,
    GET_REQUEST,
    REQUEST_FAIL,
    LIST_REQUESTS,
    GET_REQUESTS_SUBSCRIPTION,
    CLEAR_REQUEST,
  } from '../actions/types';

  const initialState = {
    Requests: [],
    Request: null,
    loading: true,
    error:{}
  };

  export default function (state = initialState, action) {
        const {type, payload} = action;

        switch(type) {
            case UPDATE_REQUEST:
            case CREATE_REQUEST:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    ...payload,
                    loading: false
                };
            case GET_REQUEST:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    Request: payload,
                    loading: false
                };         
            case LIST_REQUESTS:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    Requests:payload,
                    loading: false
                };
            case GET_REQUESTS_SUBSCRIPTION:
                return {
                    ...state,              
                    Requests:[payload, ...state.requests],
                    loading: false
                    };
            case CLEAR_REQUEST:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    Request: null             
                };
            case REQUEST_FAIL:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    error: payload,
                    loading: false
                };
            default:
                return state;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Is your `state` undefined in the `connect` HOC, or have you not referenced into your state object correctly for the `requestList` object destructuring in `props`?

Comment: my initial state in my redux is 'Requests: [ ]' which should be referenced by the mapStateToProps func in the component in combination with the useEffect and connect. If there is a way to test, please advise

Comment: I was really just asking for where the error said "Requests of undefined" was occurring. I see two lines in your snippet. Do you have the redux-devtools installed and have the browser extension? Is the reducer slice in `combineReducers` named `Requests`? I.E. is it really `state.Reducers.Reducers` to get to the array?

Comment: initially the following line is undefined when required:  requestList: PropTypes.object.isRequired in the propTypes object

Answer (score 0):

Add one opening curly and try

from

```
const MyRequestList = (requestlistbyowner, requestList: {Requests, loading}}) => {}
```

to

```
const MyRequestList = ({requestlistbyowner, requestList: {Requests, loading}}) => {}
```

Put null check before checking the length of the array to avoid errors

```
{Requests && Requests.length > 0 ?  ()}
```

Comment: If anything it is missing the opening curly bracket for props object destructuring.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in the question not the original code. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: The issue isn't that `Requests` is undefined, but rather, the object the `Requests` property is being accessed from is undefined.

Comment: yes, I am unsure what I am doing wrong when defining it in my reducer and mapStateToProps though

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue exactly where Drew Reese pointed out how the Requests Line is undefined.

The original code: `requestList: state.Requests` was using 'Requests' as if it could access this particular piece of state from the initialState object in the reducer file.

The new code: `requestList: state.request` is actually just referencing 'request' which is the name of the Reducer file which contains the WHOLE state and that is why I can unpack the 'Requests , loading' object in the props.

TY StackOverflow